# Prevent infinite loop in htaccess RewriteRule that adds and removes query string from the request URI

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have something like the following in my .htaccess file

```
# adds parameter to check first part of path
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)query=(.*)($|&)
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?path/to/file %{REQUEST_URI}?query=$1 [R,L]

# 404 if query parameter is empty
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)query=($|&)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /404.html? [R,L]
# else remove querystring before the request is finished
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)query=(.*)($|&)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [L]
```

However, it causes infinite loop when querystring is removed. I think the first rule is executing again and again after that.

Is it possible to prevent this infinite loop in any way? Something like ending the request after the querystring is removed, or prevent executing the first rule again after that...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your first `RewriteCond` based on `THE_REQUEST` instead of `QUERY_STRING`:

```
# adds parameter to check first part of path
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?(?!.*?query=[^&]+)\S+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+/)?path/to/file %{REQUEST_URI}?query=$1 [R,L]

# 404 if query parameter is empty
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)query=($|&)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /404.html? [R,L]
# else remove querystring before the request is finished
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)query=[^&]+
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [L]
```